# Error: No valid exports main found for (Module path)

Tags: node.js, npm, backend, node-modules, koa

I was reorganising documents on my mac and I have accidentally broken an app I am building.
I noticed the package.json had been removed along with the router.js. I added both files back and the koa dependency in package.json to test.

**CONSOLE ERROR**

```
Error: No valid exports main found for '/Users/devunderdog/Work space/Fantasy_Sports_Manager_Server/node_modules/koa'

at resolveExportsTarget (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:611:9)
at applyExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:492:14)
at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:541:12)
at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:22)
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:941:27)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:847:27)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1016:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:69:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/devunderdog/Work space/Fantasy_Sports_Manager_Server/index.js:1:13)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1121:30) {

  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

**INDEX.JS**

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const app = new Koa();
```

This is where the "koa" require in index.js is trying to fetch the module.
[Incorrect module path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFXw1.png)

```
module "/Users/devunderdog/Library/Caches/typescript/3.9/node_modules/@types/koa/index"
```

**PACKAGE.JSON**

```
   {
      "name": "fantasy_sports_manager_server",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "A fantasy sports management system designed to help you pick the best players based on their return on investment.",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
      },
      "author": "Lello De Luca",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "koa": "^2.13.0"
      }
    }
```

**ALREADY TRIED**

- Removing /node_modules/ and npm install
- Update NodeJS to v14.5.0
- Removing and adding all required dependencies from package.json

Thanks in advance for any effort. Let me know if you need more code to reproduce.

Devunderdog

Comment: Use `nvm install <node.js-version>` to choice others nodejs environment, I have same issue with other package. And I'm tring use the **node lts/erbium**.

Comment: Thank you very much for the input. I have seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix the problem.

- **Uninstall NodeJS, NPM and NVM** | Here is how on Mac OS [How do I completely uninstall Node.js, and reinstall from beginning (Mac OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x)
- **Install NVM(Node Version Manager)** | Here is a decent Guide again for Mac OS https://nodesource.com/blog/installing-node-js-tutorial-using-nvm-on-mac-os-x-and-ubuntu/
- **Install NodeJS with NVM** | I installed v14.5.0 and it is working great.

I believe I may have moved the root/.nvm directory by mistake and uninstalling and reinstalling has fixed that. The error is gone.

Let me know if anyone is not coming right and we could try to reproduce and fix the issue together.

Answer (score 1):

Just removing node_module/ and reinstalling doesn't resolve this problem,
upgrading node worked for me.

You can do this process manually, or with Homebrew if you’re using **MacOS**, or you may do it with **linuxbrew** on **Windows**.

- run the following commands to upgrade Node version on **macOS**:

  `$ brew update
  $ brew upgrade node`
- After Node was upgraded, run the following commands to remove and reinstall /node_modules/.

  `$ rm -rf node_modules
  $ npm ci`

> *[npm ci](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-ci) to install the project with a clean slate.*